# Unable to change label on input:checked

Tags: styled-components

I'm attempting to follow this example (https://codesandbox.io/s/oYQ21A4wz) in a larger form and am really struggling to figure out how to change the label of the input on a :checked state for a styled-component in React. I'm using the 4.2 of styled-components. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated as I've been staring at this for a couple days.

I'm able to get the parent selectors working in other cases (eg: hover) but for some reason I cannot seem to target the Label from its child.

```
const CheckBoxDoors = props => {
  const Label = styled.label`
    display: inline-block;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    border: 2px solid rgba(139, 139, 139, 0.3);
    color: #adadad;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 1px 4px;
    margin: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
  `;
  const Input = styled.input`
    &:checked + ${Label} {
      background: blue;
    }
  `;

  return (
    <div className="form-group, checkbox">
      <CheckboxContainer>
        <CheckboxTitle>{props.title}</CheckboxTitle>
        <CheckboxGroup>
          {props.options.map(option => {
            return (
              <Label key={option} className="checkbox-inline">
                <Input
                  id={props.value}
                  name={props.name}
                  onChange={props.handleChange}
                  value={props.name + ' ' + option}
                  checked={
                    props.selectedOptions.indexOf(props.name + ' ' + option) >
                    -1
                  }
                  type="checkbox"
                />
                {option}
              </Label>
            );
          })}
        </CheckboxGroup>
      </CheckboxContainer>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this one out:

```
const Input = styled.input`
  &:checked + ${Label} {
    background: blue;
  }
`;
```

This rule `&:checked + ${Label}` means 'when I am checked, the sibling Label component right below me will have these styles'; i.e

```
<>
  <Input id={id}... />
  <Label htmlFor={id}... />
</>
```

However, your component structure looks like this:

```
<Label>
  <Input ... />
</Label>
```

You'd have to change it to the structure mentioned above.

---

Also note that you shouldn't declare your styled components inside another component, it'll hurt performance badly. Instead, you should do:

```
const Input = styled.input` ... `
const Label = styled.label` ... `

const CheckBoxDoors = props => ...
```

Comment: Bingo! Thanks for that explanation, Derek. I was misunderstanding how to structure label and input. Moving those around, fixed the issue. Also pulling out the constructors from each other, sped things up considerably. You really made my day. Fixed!!

Comment: I'm glad it helped!